# Index/Sumproduct with 3 criteria

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to lookup a value from another table based on a reference table.

See below my data sample:

SHEET 1 ("CalculationLiability"):

[image]

SHEET 2 ("KeyMetrics"):

[image]

In sheet 1, cell G7 I am trying to look up the value from Sheet 2 based on 3 criteria (supplier unique ID, type and season) I tried the following formula, but it is returning a #REF error.

```
=INDEX(KeyMetrics!$F$6:$AS$100,
         SUMPRODUCT((KeyMetrics!$D$6:$D$39=CalculationLiability!$D7)*
                    (KeyMetrics!$E$6:$E$39=CalculationLiability!$G$6)*
                    (KeyMetrics!$F$5:$AS$5=CalculationLiability!$E7)))
```

Anyone knows what I am doing wrong here? I can get it to work for two criteria, but for three criteria it doesn't work. Any help or push into the right direction is much appreciated!

Comment: Step through the formula with the **Evaluate Formula** tool on the Formulas ribbon. That should help you identify the problem.

Comment: I tried that, the error seems to be referring to the Index part of the formula - there is no evaluation error for the sum-product part of the equation.

Comment: Your formula does not make a lot of sense. You need two arguments after the index range, one for the row and one for the column of the range. The sumproduct produces only one argument and that argument is a count of something, not a row or a column number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Index uses a multi column, multi row reference. That means that you need two additional arguments, one argument for row, and another for column.

Your formula currently only provides one additional argument. When you step through the formula with the Evaluate Formula tool you can see that in the last step.

[image]

You can use an Index with two Match functions. The first one to find the row, the second one to find the column.

```
=INDEX(KeyMetrics!$F$6:$AS$100,
 MATCH($D7&$G$6,INDEX(KeyMetrics!$D$6:$D$100&KeyMetrics!$E$6:$E$100,0),0),
 MATCH(CalculationLiability!E7,KeyMetrics!$F$5:$AS$5))
```

You can also use Sumproduct, but in that case, don't use Index.

```
=SUMPRODUCT(KeyMetrics!$F$6:$AS$39,
    (KeyMetrics!$D$6:$D$39=CalculationLiability!$D7)*
    (KeyMetrics!$E$6:$E$39=CalculationLiability!$G$6)*
    (KeyMetrics!$F$5:$AS$5=CalculationLiability!$E7))
```